# Passing model from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

After Learning Jon Galloways [MVC Music Store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) Example.I Just didn't understood the create view How to pass model to controller in which we could see  it from parameter in the action `Create(Movie movie).` Thanks.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Movies.Add(movie);//Where is the movie come from?
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(movie);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code example you have posted, the Movie model will be created through model binding. During this process any of your form variables will be matched up with the object specified in the action.

For instance the value of

```
<input type="text" name="Title"/>
```

would be assigned to movie's Title property.

A view can be associated with a model by declaring (Razor syntax)

```
@model GallowaySample.Movie
```

Comment: So in this process, building model instance which will be passed to controller is done automatically by Asp.net MVC? Thanks

Comment: For this create action yes. In an Index action which typically is a list of models, You would create them.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you do not pass the model to the controller, but you create an instance of your model in your controller.